# What is class meta in model?

Tags: python, django, model

Recently I am doing a function that need to customize max length of User model. Now I know that I have learned how to solve my requirement.

When I type this code, I can extend max_length:

```
User._meta.get_field('username').max_length = 100
User._meta.get_field('email').max_length = 100
```

I still can't understand what meta is. When I try to read Django document about meta model, I just know that I should how to use meta. I need more explanation that let me really understand the inner meaning about meta.

Model Meta relative link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#meta-options

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#meta-options

Comment: It is recommended you use a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) rather than changing the fields in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#meta-options):

> > Model metadata is “anything that’s not a field”, such as ordering options (**ordering**), database table name (**db_table**), or human-readable singular and plural names (**verbose_name** and **verbose_name_plural**). None are required, and adding class Meta to a model is completely ***optional***.

Thus, `Meta` is just a container class responsible for holding `metadata` information attached to the model. It defines such things as available permissions, associated database table name, whether the model is abstract or not, singular and plural versions of the name etc.

For the available `Meta` options, you can take a look at [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/).

---

As for your question, I would definitely avoid changing `max_length` to some other value like that, as you know, `max_length` also creates a `database constraint` such as `VARCHAR(64)` which can't be automatically updated to a new value `(100)` by Django.

Thus, if you want to change `max length`, make sure you also update the size of the column in the corresponding table column in the database:

For MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE auth_user MODIFY username VARCHAR(100);
```

For PostgreSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE auth_user ALTER COLUMN username TYPE VARCHAR(100);
```